# Sending Post request to Gerrit REST API from javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, gerrit

I'm working ok an Chrome Extension to improve Gerrit Experience. For that I'm using [Gerrit REST API](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12.1/index.html) with [restful.js](https://github.com/marmelab/restful.js/tree/0.7).

For all requests where anonymous access was allowed that method work pretty fine. But I could not perform a POST request, to submit a review for example.

Please, consider this code:

```
api = restful(options.gerritUrl).prefixUrl(options.prefix);
var obj = {"labels":{"Code-Review":2},"strict_labels":true,"drafts":"PUBLISH_ALL_REVISIONS"};
api.all("a/changes/{id}/revisions/{revision}/review/").post(obj)
   .then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
    })
   .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

I always get an 403 error saying:

> Invalid authentication method. In order to authenticate, prefix the REST endpoint URL with /a/ (e.g. http://example.com/a/projects/).

But as you can see I'm already using `a/changes` as required.

Debugging a real request made by an user interaction I can see a `X-Gerrit-Auth` property on header. But I could not find any specification on how to find it or how to use it on a request

Comment: Links provided match the version I'm using.

Gerrit: Testing on my work, don't have access to upgrade. 
Restful.js: Newer versions use ES6, and I'm a beginner to it, not confident enough to use it for now.